# How to save file in subfolder using php

Tags: php

I have a script with a mysql query which saves a file called *invoice.xml* every day automatically by running a cron job. In case no data is found a *no_orders.txt* is saved.

I would like this file not be saved to the same folder as the *script.php* file is in but to a subfolder called *invoices*.

The renaming of the old *invoice.xml* is done with the following code

```
 // rename old file
$nowshort = date("Y-m-d");
if(file_exists('invoice.xml')) {
  rename('invoice.xml','invoice_'.$nowshort.'.xml');
}
```

The saving is done with the following code:

```
if($xml1 !='') {    
    $File = "invoice.xml"; 
     $Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
     fwrite($Handle, $xml1);  
     print "Data Written - ".$nowMysql; 
     fclose($Handle); 
    #print $xml;
    die();
} else {
     print "No new orders - ".$nowMysql; 
     $File = "no_orders_".$nowshort.".txt"; 
     $Handle = fopen($File, 'w');  
     fclose($Handle);
     die();
}
```

Could I please get assistance how to save this file to a subfolder. Also the renaming of the existing file would need to be within the subfolder then. I have already tried with possibilities like *../invoice/invoice.xml* but unfortunately without any success.

Thank you

Comment: Use `invoice/invoice.xml` as the path, the `../` bit says go back one folder and then look for a folder called `invoice`

Comment: Also, you would require to give write privileges for the folder to the www-data user

Comment: Thank you. invoice/invoice.xml works perfectly. I also of course have the rights to write in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just give the path of file 'invoice.xml' to $File. 
Otherwise create some $Dir object which will point to Folder named 'invoice', then use accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Use `__DIR__` [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) to retrieve your script.php directory, then you can append /invoice/invoice.xml .

Example if path to your script php something like this:
/var/www/path/to/script.php

```
$currentDir = __DIR__; //this wil return /var/www/path/to
$invoicePath = $currentDir.'/invoice/invoice.xml';
```